# Error to apply function map to reply a correlation in whole df

Tags: r, dataframe, dictionary, apply, purrr

I'm trying apply function map to make a correlation with whole `df`.

```
   mt_6 <- as.matrix(df_a[,6])
   mt_7 <- as.matrix(df_a[,7])

   df_a1 <- as.data.frame(df_a[,8:18])
   df_a2 <- as.data.frame(df_a[,19:29])
   df_a3 <- as.data.frame(df_a[,30:40])
   df_a4 <- as.data.frame(df_a[,41:46])

   df_a1 %>% map( function (i) {cor.test (i~mt_6, method = "spearman")} )
```

but I received this error

> Error in cor.test.formula(i ~ mt_6, method = "spearman") : 
>     'formula' missing or invalid

Comment: Try `df_a1 %>% map(~cor.test(.x, mt_6, method = "spearman"))`

Comment: It worked, thank sou much!